# Construct2 - Detect device type

Tags: plugins, construct-2

I want to write small multiplatform game. 
I created Contruct2 plugin for my game and i have any specific methods for different operation system.

How can i detect device type in plugins runtime.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

```
if (this.runtime.isAndroid) {
    // ...
} else if (this.runtime.isiOS) {
    // ...
} else if (this.runtime.isWindowsPhone8 || this.runtime.isWindowsPhone81) {
    // ...
}
```